# Creating a password scrambler

Tags: javascript, c, code-conversion, scramble

I'm trying to copy a password scrambler from `Javascript` to `C`. What it does is take the ASCII character code of the letter, floor it, divide it, and grab a random character out of a given list.

Javascript version:

```
function getScrambledPassword(pwd) {
    var cipher = ['k', 's', 'z', 'h', 'x', 'b', 'p', 'j', 'v', 'c', 'g', 'f', 'q', 'n', 't', 'm'];
    var result="";
    if (pwd == null)
        pwd = "";
    pwd = encodeURIComponent(pwd);
    //alert("encoded password: " + pwd);
    for(var i=0;i<pwd.length;i++) {
            var cc = pwd.charCodeAt(i);
        result += cipher[Math.floor(cc/16)] + cipher[cc%16];
    }
    //alert("scrambled password: " + result);
    return result;
}
```

Example of the scrambler being run: https://jsfiddle.net/w5db66va/

What I've done so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

static char *scramblePassword(char *pwd)
{
    char *cipher[] = {
        "k", "s", "z", "h",
        "x", "b", "p", "j",
        "v", "c", "g", "f",
        "q", "n", "t", "m"
    };

    char *result = "";
    for(int i=0; i < strlen(pwd); i++)
    {
        int cc = (int) pwd[i];
        printf("%d", cc);
        result + cipher[floor(cc/16)] + cipher[cc%16];
    }
    return *result;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *test[] = {"test", "testtwo", "testthree"};
    for (int i=0;i < sizeof(test); i++)
    {
        printf("Original: %s", test[i]);
        printf("Scrambled: %s", scramblePassword(test[i]));
    }
}
```

The issue I'm experiencing is that when I run the `c` file (after compilation) it will not output anything at all. What am I doing wrong to the point that I cannot get this to run as I'd expect it?

Comment: How about `char cipher[] = { 'k', 's', ..... }` or `char cipher[] = "ksz...";`

Comment: Even better would be to make it `sizeof(test) / sizeof(char*)` so you actually get the length of the array and not its size in bytes.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Why the `'` over `"`?

Comment: In the code posted, inside the for loop, the line starting with `result +` does nothing. It should probably be `result[i] = `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing from the comment, your problems run a bit deeper than you may first think. To begin, you do not want `cipher` to be an **array of strings**, you simply want it to be a character array, e.g.:

```
    char cipher[] = "kszhxbpjvcgfqnm";
```

Next, you cannot return an array that is declared within the body of a function. The memory for `result` is destroyed when `scramblePassword` returns. Your choices are (1) dynamically allocate `result` in `scramblePassword` (and free it in `main`), or (2) declare storage for `result` in `main` and pass it as a parameter to `scramblePassword`. e.g.:

```
#define MAX 32

static char *scramblePassword (char *pwd, char *result)
{
 ...
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    char result[MAX] = "";
    ...
        printf ("Scrambled: %s\n", scramblePassword (test[i], result));
```

Finally, your algorithm, if intended to build an array of scrambled characters from `cipher` will result in choosing indexes beyond the bounds of `cipher` resulting in ***undefined behavior***. If the intent is to just assign a value to `result[x]` regardless of whether it is a valid printable ASCII value, then it may be OK. But if the first is your goal, the results of the algorithm must always result in a value that is within the bounds of `cipher`, e.g. something like:

```
         result[i] = cipher[((int)floor (cc / 16) + cc % 16) % sizeof cipher];
```

Putting all those pieces together, and recalling that `main` is type `int` and therefore returns a value, you could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 32

static char *scramblePassword (char *pwd, char *result)
{
    char cipher[] = "kszhxbpjvcgfqnm";
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < (int)strlen (pwd); i++)
    {
        int cc = (int) pwd[i];
        // result[i] = cipher[(int)floor (cc / 16)] + cipher[cc % 16];
        result[i] = cipher[((int)floor (cc / 16) + cc % 16) % sizeof cipher];
    }
    result[i] = 0;  /* you MUST nul-terminate to use as a string */

    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *test[] = {"test", "testtwo", "testthree"};
    char result[MAX] = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)(sizeof test/sizeof *test); i++)
    {
        printf ("\nOriginal : %s\n", test[i]);
        printf ("Scrambled: %s\n", scramblePassword (test[i], result));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Which would then result in readable output of:

```
$ ./bin/pwscramble

Original : test
Scrambled: ffgf

Original : testtwo
Scrambled: ffgffmb

Original : testthree
Scrambled: ffgffmcff
```

I'll leave it to you to research what that algorithm is actually supposed to do. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Also, make sure you compile with warnings enabled, e.g. `-Wall -Wextra` in your compile string and never accept code until it compiles without any warnings.  Your code was screaming at you `:)` I'm happy to answer questions until you DO get it. It is important to understand every character in C.

Comment: I do have a question, why use `(int)strlen(string)` instead of just `strlen(string)`?

Comment: That is a 'nit', but a correct 'nit'. The return of `strlen` is type `size_t` (an `unsigned` value). When used in a comparison against `i` an `int` it will result in the ***warning*** comparison of *signed* and *unsigned* values when using the `-pedantic` compiler option (which I do). So to eliminate the warning, I cast the return of `strlen` to `int`. The same applies to `(int)(sizeof test/sizeof *test)`.

Comment: Hi, when compiling I get the following error: `/tmp/ccII9slW.o: In function scramblePassword':
ciph.c:(.text+0x80): undefined reference to floor'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status` Any idea why?

Comment: You need to compile and **link** with the math library. Add `-lm` to the compile string `:)`  (that is lowercase `-LM` if the font doesn't show it clearly)

Answer (score 2):

What's happening is you are getting very lucky. Your program invokes undefined behaviour in C.

Looking at this line first

```
result + cipher[floor(cc/16)] + cipher[cc%16];
```

First of all, it doesn't do anything. That's just an expression that is thrown away. What you really wanted was:

```
result += cipher[floor(cc/16)] + cipher[cc%16];
```

But it still wouldn't have worked because C doesn't really have the concept of a string. Strings are actually just sequences of chars terminated by '\0'. `result` is just a pointer to such a sequence and, like any other pointer, when you add something to it you just increase the location to which the pointer is pointing.

Also, returning `*result` actually dereferences the pointer and returns what it is pointing at.

The statement

```
result = "";
```

allocates a bit of memory somewhere with an empty sequence of bytes terminated with a `\0` i.e. a single nul byte. On the stack (or in a register depending on the implementation), result is allocated and given the address of the nul byte.

When you return `*result` you return the nul byte but the caller thinks you are returning a pointer so it will interpret that nul byte as a pointer (I'm surprised your code doesn't give errors when compiled actually) and that pointer will probably be a null pointer.

To concatenate strings in C is a tricky operation. You have to use `strcat` or one of its safer derivatives. You have to make sure that you allocate enough space for the result and you have to do it dynamically with malloc because strings allocated locally go away when you return from the function in whixh they were allocated.

**Edit**

And another thing....

C has more than one numeric data type. When you divide one integer by another, you get an integer result. if cc is not divisible by 16, the result will already be `floor(cc/16)`

Comment: It'll give warning, but not any errors, I just edited it a little bit, based on the comments, and got a new warning I haven't seen yet: `ciph.c:(.text+0x5a): undefined reference to `floor'`

Comment: `floor` is a C library function. I've seen it before with gcc that it doesn't link the floating point functions if there is no sign of using floating point in the program, which is another issue...

Comment: You need to link with `-lm` to be able to use the `floor` function, but do you really need the floor function ?

Answer (score 0):

C is not JS.

There are many subtle problems and your program doesn't even compile.

You probably want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

static char *scramblePassword(char *pwd, char *result)
{
  char cipher[] = {    // you need an array of chars here, not an
                       // array of pointers to char
    'k', 's', 'z', 'h',
    'x', 'b', 'p', 'j',
    'v', 'c', 'g', 'f',
    'q', 'n', 't', 'm'
  };

  size_t i;
  for (i = 0; i < strlen(pwd); i++)
  {
    int cc = (int)pwd[i];
    //printf("%d", cc);
    result[i] = cipher[/*(int)floor*/(cc / 16)] + cipher[cc % 16];
                           // ^ actually you can drop the floor function,
                           // there is no floating point here, so integer
                           // division will do the job
  }

  result[i] = 0;  // this will NUL terminate the string
  return result;
}

int main(void)
{
  char *test[] = { "test", "testtwo", "testthree" };
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(test) / sizeof(test[0]); i++)
                    // ^ the number of elements is not sizeof(test)
                    // (that's the number of bytes the array takes in memory
                    // but sizeof(test) / sizeof(test[0])
  {
    char result[100];  // you cannot return arrays in C, you need to provide
                       // the array and pass the pointer to your function
    printf("Original: %s\n", test[i]);
    printf("Scrambled: %s\n", scramblePassword(test[i], result));
  }
}
```